# Encontrar arrays com a menor distância

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Tenho um `array_objetivo` e gostaria de encontrar o id e a distância (euclidiana neste exemplo) dos `n` arrays mais próximos a ele que estão em `array_all`. Segue exemplos dos arrays.

```
array_objetivo = np.array([2,2,3,4])

array_all = np.array([[1,1,2,2],
                      [2,2,3,3],
                      [3,3,4,4],
                      [4,4,5,5]])
```

Para encontrar apenas o mais próximo, fiz:

```
def calcula_distancia(array1, array2):
    # Distância Euclidiana
    return np.linalg.norm(array1-array2)

def pega_vetor_mais_proximo(array_objetivo, array_all):

    menor_dist = calcula_distancia(array_objetivo, array_all[0])
    id_menor_dist = 0

    for i in range(1, array_all.shape[0]):
        dist = calcula_distancia(array_objetivo, array_all[i])
        if dist < menor_dist:
            menor_dist = dist
            id_menor_dist = i

    return menor_dist, id_menor_dist
```

Como posso modificar para encontrar os `n` array mais próximos de maneira eficiente?

Answer (score 0):

Não consigo digitar um código aqui da maneira que gostaria mas creio que posso te ajudar.

Você cria uma lista vazia e um loop while baseado num contador que vai receber a quantidade de distancias que deseja retornar, dentro desse while você coloca o seu loop for da maneira que está no código e no final desse for você decrementa o seu contador e deleta da lista a distancia que encontrou, caso seu array_all seja uma lista que não pode ser modificada você simplesmente cria uma variável local que recebe array_all e faz isso que te disse.

Comment: Se eu entendi direito, desta maneira eu calculo a distância do `array_objetivo` com  todas as listas do `array_all` n vezes. E ainda, quando removo uma lista do `array_all`, os ids mudam. Meu objetivo é pegar os ids das listas mais próximas.

Comment: Realmente, se você quer o ID foi um erro de interpretação meu caso precise dos valores a forma descrita atende. Uma maneira nada elegante e dependendo do código muito pesada seria usar a solução que propus e fazer um for pegando o .index de cada um dos n arrays que você pegou.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver calculando todas as distâncias e as armazenando. Depois, pego os ids dos menores valores da lista das distâncias e os retorno.

```
def pega_n_vetores_mais_proximos(array_objetivo, array_all, n):
    distancias = []

    # calcula todas as distâncias e as armazena
    for i in range(0, array_all.shape[0]):
        distancias.append(calcula_distancia(array_objetivo,array_all[i]))

    distancias = np.array(distancias)

    # pega os ids das menores distâncias
    menores_n_idx = np.argsort(distancias)[:n]

    return distancias[menores_n_idx], menores_n_idx
```